# Can't import turtle module in Python 2.x and Python 3.x

Tags: python, user-interface, turtle-graphics

I want to play with [turtle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html) module in Python. But when i do import turtle module, i've the following error:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import turtle
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                    
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                          
  File "turtle.py", line 3, in <module>                                                                                 
    myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()                                                                                                 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Turtle'
```

and for Python 3.x:

```
$ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, Sep 30 2012, 16:41:36) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import turtle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "turtle.py", line 3, in <module>
    myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Turtle'
```

I working under Kubuntu Linux 12.10. I've played with Tkinter gui. There is no problem. What happen with turtle module?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You've called a script `turtle.py`, which is shadowing the `turtle` module in the standard library. Rename it.

Comment: can you explain this more?

Comment: There is file turtle.py in current directory. I try to import turtle module. And python interpreter search turtle module and first seek turtle.py in my current folder instead of turtle.py from python library directory.

Answer (score 4):

You can fix this problem by installing the `python-tk` package.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I found answer: "Rename it!" and it worked. anyways don't use 'import turtle'. Use 'from turtle import *'.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to locate any file with `turtle.py` so I uninstalled Python and reinstalled a 64 bit version from Python.org. This time the program ran after I typed the following two lines of code into the terminal (black screen).

```
import turtle

shelly=turtle.Turtle()
```

Of course your turtle can be called other names and not necessarily `shelly`.

Answer (score 0):

before installing try using:

```
from turtle import *

g=Turtle()

begin_fill()

g.forward(100)
```

check out if this working or not(there is space between import and asterick sign)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure also that you run:

which python
Then set the top of your file with that.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import Tkinter
from turtle import *
```

Or if you don't have the location correct, you need to rename the file with .py
Then execute with python filename.py

Answer (score -3):

please try

from tutle imort Turtle: to  import the module....it will work for you

Comment: Please recheck your typo