# Python module member (turtle) not recognized

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm beginning Python, and when I started the module part of the tutorials, it looked like modules members weren't recognized.

I'm on VSCode with python extensions like "Python" and "Python for VSCode". I'm on Windows. I reinstalled Python in C:\Python32 to add it to the path, and went into my computer > properties > advance > variable to add it to the path again.

Example :

```
import os

import turtle

turtle.forward(100)

os.system("pause")
```

> Error : Module 'turtle' has no 'forward' member

Why aren't the module member understood by VSCode ? 
I tried to run the code with IDLE, and it even stopped at the turtle import :

```
import os
import turtle
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> //File should have pyshell#1 in <> in ""
>
> ```
> import turtle
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python37-32\turtle.py", line 5, in
>
> ```
> my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()       # x is not a good name for a Turtle object
> ```
>
> AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Turtle'

Comment: You have apparently named a program of yours `turtle.py`.  That's being imported instead of the actual `turtle` module.

Comment: agreed^ you probably have a file, library, or module polluting your namespace. Make sure you don't have anything named `turtle` or `Turtle`. Maybe try putting your code in a codepen so we can take a look at it.

Comment: That was it indeed, I called my testing file "turtle.py", since it was about turtle. 

Thanks a lot to both of you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably your file name is turtle.py , rename it and give a try .

More information follow this 
[Can't import turtle module in Python 2.x and Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530140/cant-import-turtle-module-in-python-2-x-and-python-3-x)